# How to set apache virtualhost to work with ipv6?

Tags: apache-2.2, ipv6, virtualhost

I've got server with 1 ipv4 address and with a few ipv6 addresses.
One domain is redirected to ipv4 A record
I set up apache ports.conf like this:

```
Listen ip.v4.address:80
NameVirtualHost ip.v4.address:80
```

and virtualhost file:

```
<VirtualHost ip.v4.address:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/first/
ServerName first.domain
ServerAlias www.first.domain
ErrorLog ...
CustomLog ...
</VirtualHost>
```

And everything works fine.

Now I want to create new virtualhost for second domain with second ip.
I redirected second domain to ipv6 AAAA record,
add to ports.conf:

```
Listen [ip.v6.address]:80
NameVirtualHost [ip.v6.address]:80
```

create new virtualhost file:

```
<VirtualHost [ip.v6.address]:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/second/
ServerName second.domain
ServerAlias www.second.domain
ErrorLog ...
CustomLog ...
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart Apache.
There was no errors on server start but it doesn't work.
When I enter second domain in the browser the server is not found.
When I enter `[ip.v6.address]` site shows up.

Any help?

Comment: Thanks for help everyone. IPv6 is correct and I need two different sites. I contacted my domain provider where I set up this AAAA record. They said it can take 24h to set it up and maybe here is the problem. When I set up A record the effect was almost immediate and I thought AAAA works the same way.

Comment: It would be nice if you marked your favourite answer as such, so that the people who tried to help you get some reward for doing so ;-)

Answer (score 18):

Your apache config looks correct, but a little more complex than it needs to be if you want one site to be reachable over both IPv4 and IPv6 (dual stack).

Instead of

```
<VirtualHost ip.v4.address:80>
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost [ip.v6.address]:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

you can do

```
<VirtualHost ip.v4.address:80 [ip.v6.address]:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

That way the single virtual hosts listens on both IP addresses. It is a lot easier to maintain!

If you really want a different site on IPv6 then your configuration is correct of course.

Comment: Or maybe <VirtualHost *:80> ?

Comment: That could certainly work as well, but since he explicitly specified the IP addresses in his example I did so as well. If you don't really care about the IP address and just want to do everything by the Host: header then your solution is much easier. Watch out with SSL/TLS sites though. You need to make sure that Server Name Indication (TLS/SNI) works for your user base.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like an IPv6 name resolution error rather than an Apache error. Check that the name resolves correctly to the address.

Answer (score 3):

Does the name resolve to the correct IPv6 address? This seems to be problem in domain resolution.